# Promise.all throwing type error when calling multiple async functions with different return types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 3 types:

```
export interface Animal {
...
}

export interface Cat extends Animal{
...
}

export interface Dog extends Animal{
...
}

export interface Iguana extends Animal {
...
}
```

In a separate file I have defined 3 async functions with the following syntax:

```
const task1 = (() => Promise<Cat[]>) = async () => {
...
}

const task2 = (() => Promise<Dog[]>) = async () => {
...
}

const task3 = (() => Promise<Iguana[]>) = async () => {
...
}

const tasks = [task1, task2, task3];
const runningTasks = tasks.map(task => task());
// below line throws an error
const results = await Promise.all(runningTasks);
```

The last line throws an error because of type incompatibility, and it's extremely long and basically says "Dog is missing properties from Cat".

What I am trying to do is simply call these 3 functions asyncronously and save their results.

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps have them return the base type `Animal`?

Comment: i thought about that and as you suspect the error is resolved, but then I am not sure whether that actually allows me to use the specific types from the results, which is important to me.

Comment: I'm looking at the type signature of `all` and it seems like the problem is that it expects one particular type T and all values passed into the function are of the same type T and thus it returns a T[]

Comment: Hmm another option would be to define a class with one property for each output.

Comment: The easiest way out of this is probably to assert that `runningTasks` is the tuple type you expect:  `const runningTasks = tasks.map(task => task()) as [Promise<Cat[]>, Promise<Dog[]>, Promise<Iguana[]>];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is simply call these 3 functions asyncronously and save their results.

You have this kind of set up:

```js
export interface Animal {
    name: string;
}

export interface Cat extends Animal {
    attitude: string;
}

export interface Dog extends Animal {
    sleepDuration: number;
}

export interface Iguana extends Animal {
    skinToughness: number;
}

const task1 = async (): Promise<Cat[]> => {
    return await Promise.resolve([]);
}

const task2 = async (): Promise<Dog[]> => {
    return await Promise.resolve([]);
}

const task3 = async (): Promise<Iguana[]> => {
    return await Promise.resolve([]);
}
```

One approach is to use the parent type in the `Promise` like this:

```
const demo = async () => {
    const tasks = [task1, task2, task3];
    const runningTasks: Promise<Animal[]>[] = tasks.map(task => task());
    const results: Animal[][] = await Promise.all(runningTasks);
}
```

If it is important to use the specific types from the results, the tuple that jcalz suggested would work:

```
const demo = async () => {
    const tasks = [task1, task2, task3] as const;

    type TaskResults = [
        ReturnType<typeof task1>,
        ReturnType<typeof task2>,
        ReturnType<typeof task3>,
    ];

    const runningTasks = tasks.map(task => task()) as TaskResults;
    const results = await Promise.all(runningTasks);

    results[0][0].attitude;
    results[1][0].sleepDuration;
    results[2][0].skinToughness;
}
```

Surprisingly, if you do not need to start the tasks ahead of time then you can maintain type information with this approach:

```
const demo = async () => {

    const results = await Promise.all([
        task1(),
        task2(),
        task3()
    ])

    results[0][0].attitude;
    results[1][0].sleepDuration;
    results[2][0].skinToughness;
}
```

Comment: Here is a follow up question/answer that creates a `MapToReturnType`, which can take the place of the manual type creation of `TaskResults` wiith `MapToReturnType<typeof tasks>`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56160793/1108891