# Create a tuple type of return types from an array of functions so we can cast the result of `map` with that tuple type

Tags: typescript, types

In answering this question [Promise.all throwing type error when calling multiple async functions with different return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158662/promise-all-throwing-type-error-when-calling-multiple-async-functions-with-diffe/56160190#56160190) I can across this puzzle.

We have these three functions:

```js
const func1 = (): RegExp => { throw new Error(); }
const func2 = (): number => { throw new Error(); }
const func3 = (): Date => { throw new Error(); }

const funcs = [func1, func2, func3] as const;
```

We want to run a `map` on that `funcs` array, invoke each `func`, and maintain type safety in the resulting array of return values.

This works:

```js
type Results = [
    ReturnType<typeof func1>,
    ReturnType<typeof func2>,
    ReturnType<typeof func3>,
];

const results = funcs.map(task => task()) as Results;

results[0].test('');
results[1].toExponential();
results[2].toTimeString();
```

This fails:

```js
type MapToReturnType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends () => any ? ReturnType<T[K]> : never;
};

// type TaskResultsToo = readonly [RegExp, number, Date]
type ResultsToo = MapToReturnType<typeof funcs>;

// Conversion of type '(number | RegExp | Date)[]' to type 
// 'readonly [RegExp, number, Date]' may be a mistake because 
// neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this 
// was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
// Type '(number | RegExp | Date)[]' is missing the following 
// properties from type 'readonly [RegExp, number, Date]': 0, 1, 2
const resultsToo = funcs.map(task => task()) as ResultsToo;
```

How can we change `MapToReturnType<T>` to produce the `Results` that work? I sense that it has something to do with that `readonly` modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `as const` produces a `readonly` tuple. Since `MapToReturnType` is homomorphic it will preserve modifiers, so if you pass in a `readonly` tuple  you get a `readonly` tuple out.

Since `map` produces a simple mutable array, typescript will not let you directly type assert to a readonly tuple.

The simple solution is to us a double assertion `as unknown as ResultsToo`. The elegant solution is to remove the `readonly` modifier when mapping:

```
const func1 = (): RegExp => { throw new Error(); }
const func2 = (): number => { throw new Error(); }
const func3 = (): Date => { throw new Error(); }

const funcs = [func1, func2, func3] as const;

type MapToReturnType<T> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends () => any ? ReturnType<T[K]> : never;
};

// type TaskResultsToo = readonly [RegExp, number, Date]
type ResultsToo = MapToReturnType<typeof funcs>;

const resultsToo = funcs.map(task => task()) as ResultsToo;
```